# What is SYCL 1.2?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow

```
Please specify the location where ComputeCpp for SYCL 1.2 is installed. [Default is /usr/local/computecpp]: 
Invalid SYCL 1.2 library path. /usr/local/computecpp/lib/libComputeCpp.so cannot be found
```

What should I do?What is SYCL 1.2?

Comment: Did you try to enable OpenCL during ./configure step? This error shouldn't come up if you use defaults (hit enter to use default)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Ok,I see now,thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[SYCL](https://www.khronos.org/sycl) is a C++ abstraction layer for OpenCL. TensorFlow's [experimental support](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/tensorflow%E2%84%A2-for-opencl%E2%84%A2-using-sycl%E2%84%A2) for OpenCL uses SYCL, in conjunction with a SYCL-aware C++ compiler.

As Yaroslav pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831214/what-is-sycl-1-2#comment70853775_41831214), SYCL is only required if you are building TensorFlow with OpenCL support. The following question during the execution of `./configure` asks about OpenCL support:

```
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N]
```

If you answer `N`, you will not have to supply a SYCL path.

Comment: The OpenCL implementation of TensorFlow is currently using ComputeCpp, an implementation of SYCL. You can download this here https://www.codeplay.com/products/computesuite/computecpp and when requested point at the root of this extracted archive.

Answer (score 2):

It is optional step so you can skip if you want.

OpenCL (Open Computing Language) is a framework for writing programs that execute across heterogeneous platforms consisting of central processing units (CPUs), graphics processing units (GPUs), digital signal processors (DSPs), field-programmable gate arrays (FPGAs) and other processors or hardware accelerators.

so if you want to intall you have to Setting Up TensorFlow With OpenCL Using SYCL bellow link provide step by step information about it
https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/getting-started-with-tensorflow